# Ajax não retorna valores em dispositivo móvel

Tags: jquery, ajax

beleza? É o seguinte, tenho um método ajax que retorna um json, o problema é que esse ajax não é executado em dispositivos móveis. Sempre me retorna fail, contudo, no pc, tudo acontece normalmente.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "get",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(retorno){
            for(var i = 0; i < retorno.myArrayList.length; i++) {
                if(retorno.myArrayList[i].map.status == 1) {
                    retorno.myArrayList[i].map.status = "Aberta"
                } else if(retorno.myArrayList[i].map.status == 2) {
                    retorno.myArrayList[i].map.status = "Paga"
                } else {
                    retorno.myArrayList[i].map.status = "Cancelada"
                }

                linha += '<tr>';
                linha +=    '<td>' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.nomePaciente + '</td>';
                linha +=    '<td><a href="'+ retorno.myArrayList[i].map.idFatura + '" data-fatura="' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.idFatura + '">' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.nomeFatura + '</a></td>';
                linha +=    '<td>' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.valorFatura.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}) + '</td>';
                linha +=    '<td>' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.vencimento + '</td>';
                linha +=    '<td>' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.dataPagamento + '</td>';
                linha +=    '<td>' + retorno.myArrayList[i].map.status + '</td>';
                linha += '</tr>';

                totalRec += retorno.myArrayList[i].map.valorFatura;
            }

            table.append(linha);
            retorno = "";
            $(".tr-modal").text(totalRec.toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}))
            $(".modalConta-back").fadeIn();
            $(".modalConta").css("transform", "translateX(0)");

        }).fail(function(erro){
            alert(erro);
        });
```

A requisição sempre dá fail mas no pc tudo ocorre normalmente. O fail até retorna um objeto mas não consigo manipular nem verificar o erro ou o pq não gera o json no celular.

Eu gero a url através do jquery quando clica na linha da tabela.

```
var dia = ($(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text() < 10) ? "0" + $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text() : $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
var mes = $("#month").val();
var ano = $("#year").val();
var url = http://localhost:8080/meusite/api/findAllContatoFaturasJson.do?day="+ dia + "&month=" + mes + "&year=" + ano +"&tipo=2&p1=0&dentistaId=&vendedorId=&formaPagamentoId=";
```

Comment: _"não gera o json no celular."_ ? Já testaste `alert(JSON.stringify(erro));`? Ou criar uma `div` para fazer logs como esse e usar `logDiv.textContent = JSON.stringify(erro);`

Comment: Está *bastante vago*, no celular esta rodando via HTTP ou é algum asset em webView? Qual a mensagem de erro do fail? Dê detalhes.

Comment: A URL é a mesma em ambos os ambientes? O celular consegue alcançar a URL?

Comment: Sim, a url é formada via javascript. Anexei o código tbm para verem. Então, ao clicar na linha, a url é gerada, anexada ao ajax e retornado o json. Ou deveria ser assim no celular tbm. Pelo json stringy recomendado pelo Sergio, dá a seguinte mensagem: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: localhost não vai funcionar no celular, vai precisar colocar o IP do seu computador para que ele consiga localizar os dados

Comment: ou colocar a url sem o  `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: Daniel, exatamente isso. Inseri o ip do meu dispositivo e funcionou certinho no celular. valeu ae!!!!

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na sua URL, o host está definido como `localhost`, e a porta 8080, como está rodando no celular o navegador não vai conseguir encontrar as informações. Você pode remover o `http://localhost:8080` da url, dessa forma ele não tentar acessar por esse endereço, mas sim pelo caminho relativo.

Por exemplo, se o endereço que você digitou no celular para acessar a url foi `http://192.168.0.100/index`, definindo sem o `http://localhost:8080` ele vai tentar localizar por `http://192.168.0.100/meusite/api/findAllContatoFaturasJson.do...`

Comment: Daniel, tente fazer como vc sugeriu mas aí o apache não consegue processar a requisição. De qualquer forma vou fazer o upload pro servidor, e ver como vai se comportar essa requisição no celular. Posto os detalhes depois.